# Using jQuery to handle the form submit event isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sure it's something obvious but my JavaScript is really rusty... here's the event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(){
        // this is never reached
    });
});
```

and here's the submit button:

```
<input type="button" id="__E340" class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="Save" onclick="__E340_onclick();" role="button">
```

Could this have something to do with the button being of type button, not submit? I can't search for the button by ID or class because the button is dynamically generated and the ID is not guaranteed to be the same if you refresh the page, and none of the CSS classes assigned to the button are unique to it.

Comment: probably because your input is `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`, so submit listener is never called. (voting to close as typo)

Comment: Oh, I see, I was wondering about that. Guess I'll need to find out where the button is being generated and change it to `type="submit"`, though I wonder if that might break something else...

Comment: No need for `type="submit"` just remove the `type` attribute.

Comment: maybe since you are not generating the HTML, you can add a listener to the button and then trigger the submit "manually", something like: `$("#__E340").on("click", function(){$("form").trigger("submit")})`