# How do I cancel a button click event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried doing it two different ways:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[type=button]').on('click', function(evt){
        if ($(this).val() == 'Close')
          return true;
        var totalHours = 999; // here I am computing a total number of hours but that is irrelevant to my question
        var reportedTotalHours = parseFloat($("#TotalHours").text());
        var difference = Math.abs(totalHours - reportedTotalHours);
        if (difference >= 0.25) // discrepancy must be less than a quarter hour
        {
          alert("Total of hours for each activity must equal " + reportedTotalHours + ".");
          evt.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

`return false;` should be cancelling the button click, as should `evt.preventDefault();`, but neither of them is working for me. What happens when the button is clicked is the form is submitted, but I want to prevent the form from being submitted until the discrepancy in hours is less than 0.25.

Comment: Are you sure this is the button submitting the form? `type="button"` usually doesn't submit a form. Typically it's `type="submit"`...

Comment: If you want to prevent form the submit, instead target the `submit` event of the form. That way you can do `preventDefault()` to stop the form submission.

Comment: I tried targetting the `submit` event of the form, but that didn't work for some reason; I have a question about that out there as well! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196167/using-jquery-to-handle-the-form-submit-event-isnt-working As for the button, yes, it really is `type='button'`; I don't know why. It has a script attached to its `onclick` event that submits the form. Who knows...

Comment: I could change the button to be `type='submit`' but it's dynamically generated and I'm not sure if that would break other pages...

Comment: classic case of jquery overuse. Try this neat new library instead http://vanilla-js.com

Comment: I tried changing the button to `type='submit'` but still the event won't cancel...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your input[type=button] to a button tag. Then submit your form in your onclick callback when the conditions are right.

In some browsers an input[type=button] element will submit a form if there's no input[type=submit] element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.prev')
if(true) {
        button.disabled = false
    } else {
        button.disabled = true
    }
```

```html
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).